# can't easy_install ssl module

Tags: python, ssl, easy-install

When doing `easy_install ssl` I get following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>easy_install ssl
Searching for ssl
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/ssl/
Reading http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html
Best match: ssl 1.15
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/ssl/ssl-1.15.tar.gz#md5=81ea8a1175e437b4c769ae65b3290e0c
Processing ssl-1.15.tar.gz
Running ssl-1.15\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\fipethor\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-v2d68a\ssl-1.15\egg-dist-tmp-klfhbm

error: Setup script exited with error: Python was built with Visual Studio 2003;
extensions must be built with a compiler than can generate compatible binaries.
Visual Studio 2003 was not found on this system. If you have Cygwin installed,
you can try compiling with MingW32, by passing "-c mingw32" to setup.py.
```

Comment: An obvious question maybe; but do you have Visual Studio 2003 installed? Or cygwin?

Comment: oops, sorry; no - have neither installed on my computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Visit: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=2435
2. Download & Run: Automated MinGW Installer (make sure you check the base, g++ and Make)
3. Update your PATH: Add the C:\mingw\bin directory to the system PATH
4. Create (or edit): C:\Python25\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg and add the following 2 lines:

   [build]

   compiler=mingw32

Found here:

http://old.nabble.com/Installing-PyXML-problems-td12405796.html

Comment: +1 I am not running windows but this probably the correct action.